# How to check in Play Framework if a unit test performed a database insert/update/delete

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, h2, playframework-2.2

I've got a base class that all my controller tests extend. This is set up so each unit test can have its own Fixture to load from.

So the @Before override will check what the required fixture for the test is, load it and then start the test.

The problem here is that this reloads the fixture every single time. Even if the method only did a select on the database, altering nothing.

The internal memory database the Play Framework uses is the H2 database. I wonder if there is a way to check after a unit test is done, if there has been a change to the database and if not, skip the reloading of the exact same data.

I tried identity_scope, it returns null no matter what.

Comment: I don't know if there is a possibility to achieve it with only Junit's but there is a tool in which you can easily manage this loadings. Its dbunit and you can easily use it in play. As far as I can tell the main purpose in Junit is to separate tests from each other. but I'm not saying that is is not possible  Maybe you could you could try with @BeforeClass with combination with test suite.

Comment: I looked it up and it looks like I'd have to refactor all my existing unit tests for this. Thanks for the suggestion but I can't put time in that.

Comment: Did you consider changing from in memory database to actual physical database?

Answer (score 2):

H2 has no possiblity of checking when were last changes applied.
However You could just make an additional column that saves last modification time with

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT, NAME VARCHAR, LAST_MOD TIMESTAMP AS NOW());
```

That way You could save a time of test start, and then query the DB if there are any modification dates after the test start time.

I don't see any other possible way

Comment: Well, it is the best idea I guess, but I would take a lot of time to make sure those columns only ever exist while unit tests are running and automatically get filled in when an insert happens. Which reminds me: what about a delete? How do I keep track that a delete has happened?

Comment: With query which I posted it will automatically change timestamp to actual time on any modification because AS NOW() executes every time record gets changed.
Creating additional field on tests isn't a good idea, but I'd say additional column won't make big difference for the whole program. Even if it'd just for testing purposes

Comment: Okay. But what about deleting a row in one test and then expecting it to be there in the next?  And still, this only works if I know what table to test. What I really need is a way to detect if any table in the entire DB has been altered.

Comment: Well I guess it isn't possible